# Unlocked package component overridden metadata components in the org

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

I created the Unlocked package (**no namespace**) with the common/dependency components like *Account, Contact fields*, and *Custom labels* which have been on Packaging org already, but I forgot and included them into the package.

So, when I created the package version and installed it to the org those components were overridden by package components. I added them by mistake and I have to return them back as they were. See below.
[image]

Those *fields* and *Custom labels* are referenced across classes that are in the package and other classes that are in the org too. I want to uninstall the package and deploy everything via **mdapi**, but I cannot uninstall the package because of dependencies between the components.

I created the separate package with those *fields* and *Custom labels* and tried to install, but got the error that it could not be overridden with another package, obviously...

Is the only way here is to manually uninstall and comment (if referenced in other org metadata) those *fields* and *Custom labels* one by one from the package, then uninstall the package and deploy everything back via **mdapi**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove metadata from being part of the Unlocked Package in the UI.
In the org where the Unlocked Package was installed, go to Setup/Installed Packages, click on your package name and then on the "View Components" button. You'll have a "Remove" button next to your elements.

This won't delete anything, just "unflag" your metadata from being part of your Unlocked Package. It will go back to the "happy soup".

You can then start from scratch, create a new Package Version with only the metadata you want, and install it again. Then you'll be able to install your 2nd package with your fields and custom labels.

Note that if you use metadata api, you can deploy whatever you want even if the metadata is already part of a package.

Comment: I thought it will delete not "unflag". Thank you!

Comment: Didn't know metadata api could deploy over unlocked package components - great answer!

Comment: Hello, I am in the same situation as the original post, for Custom Labels
Problem is, the Custom Labels are not visible in the unlocked package components UI
Is there a way to unlink Custom Labels from a package ?