# Flow from Unlocked DX package can not be changed in subscriber org. Why?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, visual-workflow, isv, unlocked-package

I just installed an unlocked package containing flows in a customer sandbox and was a bit shocked to see that the flow cannot be opened and adjusted by the customer/subscriber. I thought that's the main difference to managed packages.

**Is this restriction documented anywhere and whats the rationale behind it?**

Comment: Consider removing the flow from the unlocked package components list, as explained [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242172/unlocked-package-component-overridden-metadata-components-in-the-org/242181#242181)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the bug: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003UVoQAM

horrible stuff and I hope they put effort into getting this fixed.  The only way to edit the flows currently is to hand edit the XML in the package.

edit:  or on a scratch org.  They can be opened there.  Flows & Processes are currently inaccessible through the UI on both prod and full data sandbox

Comment: Still a bug, eight months later.  Stumbled into this issue today.