# unlink Custom Label from Unlocked Package

Tags: salesforcedx, customlabel, unlocked-package

I have a similar issue as the author of this post :
[Unlocked package component overridden metadata components in the org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242172/unlocked-package-component-overridden-metadata-components-in-the-org)

Basically, I generated an unlocked package version (org dependent) that wrongly includes Custom Labels that were already part of the org. These labels are referenced by different Apex classes and can't be deleted.

I tried to generate a new version of the package that doesn't include the labels, but they are only marked as "Managed - Installed Deleted" and are still part of the package.

I need to find a solution to "unlink" them from the package without having to remove all the references to them as the org is quite big. I can't see the Custom Labels in the Installed Packages Components UI so I can't remove them from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have a great day !

Comment: Create a whole new unlocked package rather than version the current one, that has the required metadata only.

Comment: It makes sense to create a new package, but I still would not be able to delete the old one which contains the custom labels, as those are referenced by many apex classes and other components